# How to select only return the first row when multiple rows returned in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data:

```
Id                                      Week1   Week2   Date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C0935336-B424-E911-8117-005056A82772    201906  201904  2019-02-02 00:00:00.000
18D809B1-8725-E911-8117-005056A82772    201907  201904  2019-02-09 00:00:00.000
C95855A0-9428-E911-8117-005056A82772    201908  201905  2019-02-16 00:00:00.000
5ABE80F6-2531-E911-8117-005056A82772    201909  201905  2019-02-23 00:00:00.000
6B520DE4-9445-E911-8118-005056A82772    201910  201906  2019-03-02 00:00:00.000
ADD0A8D0-EE2E-E911-8117-005056A82772    201911  201906  2019-03-09 00:00:00.000
```

As you can see, Week2 as duplicate entries and I need to return the first row of each pair of rows returned so that I end up with something similar to this.

```
Id                                      Week1   Week2   Date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C0935336-B424-E911-8117-005056A82772    201906  201904  2019-02-02 00:00:00.000
C95855A0-9428-E911-8117-005056A82772    201908  201905  2019-02-16 00:00:00.000
6B520DE4-9445-E911-8118-005056A82772    201910  201906  2019-03-02 00:00:00.000
```

I'm using the following in SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Weeks.Week2 ORDER BY Weeks.Week2) AS Row#, 
    Data.Id, Weeks.Week1, Weeks.Week2, Weeks.Date 
FROM
    Data
INNER JOIN 
    Weeks ON Data.WeekN = Weeks.Week1
INNER JOIN
    Users ON Data.UserId = Users.UserId
WHERE 
    Weeks.Week2 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Weeks.Week2
                    FROM Data
                    INNER JOIN Weeks ON Data.Week = Weeks.Week1
                    INNER JOIN Users ON Data.UserId = Users.UserId
                    WHERE Data.UserId = 1234 AND Weeks.Week1 >= 201907)
ORDER BY 
    Weeks.Week2
```

Which introduces a row number for each set or rows returned:

```
Row# Id                                     Week1   Week2   Date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    C0935336-B424-E911-8117-005056A82772   201906  201904  2019-02-02 00:00:00.000
2    18D809B1-8725-E911-8117-005056A82772   201907  201904  2019-02-09 00:00:00.000
1    C95855A0-9428-E911-8117-005056A82772   201908  201905  2019-02-16 00:00:00.000
2    5ABE80F6-2531-E911-8117-005056A82772   201909  201905  2019-02-23 00:00:00.000
1    6B520DE4-9445-E911-8118-005056A82772   201910  201906  2019-03-02 00:00:00.000
2    ADD0A8D0-EE2E-E911-8117-005056A82772   201911  201906  2019-03-09 00:00:00.000
```

My question is how do I select all the rows where the `Row#` is 1 ?

Comment: Put another `SELECT` around what you already have. `SELECT ... FROM (<your current query>) x WHERE x.row# = 1;`

Comment: @stickybit I figured it out but I removed the Order by the get it to work as if I leave it, It's throwing me an error but I think I need to leave it in: 'The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.' Any ideas?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in your `ROW_NUMBER()` expression will take care of the ordering for you. The `ORDER BY` clause in the query is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @stickybit mentioned, you can use:

```
SELECT
    Id
    , Week1
    , Week2
    , Date
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Weeks.Week2 ORDER BY Weeks.Week2) AS Row#
            , Data.Id
            , Weeks.Week1
            , Weeks.Week2
            , Weeks.Date
        FROM
            Data
            INNER JOIN Weeks ON Data.WeekN = Weeks.Week1
            INNER JOIN Users ON Data.UserId = Users.UserId
        WHERE Weeks.Week2 IN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT Weeks.Week2
                FROM
                    Data
                    INNER JOIN Weeks ON Data.Week = Weeks.Week1
                    INNER JOIN Users ON Data.UserId = Users.UserId
                WHERE
                    Data.UserId = 1234
                    AND Weeks.Week1 >= 201907
            )
    ) Q
WHERE Row# = 1
```

You don't need to worry about the `ORDER BY`, as the `ROW_NUMBER()` function is taking care of that for you in its `OVER()` clause.

You also don't need `DISTINCT`, as the `ROW_NUMBER()` function will prevent it from having any effect anyway.